# wordpress plugin is not working in the user admin panel

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I've made a plugin for my WordPress and its working fine with the admin panel.

I've given a collaborator access to a user and that user can login with his details, he has limited options on the admin menu which he can use.

The plugin is not showing on that menu can anyone tell me is it possible to give users or a specific user access of that plugin?

i need help thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide some code snippet, what you have tried, what are there in your plugin? Your question is unclear, no one can guess what have you done and what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **Adminimize** plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/ and you can set the privileges whom you need to show up the plugin when the login is successful at their sign up accounts.

Comment: im already using adminimize and that plugin is not listed in that list of Adminimize :( confused what to do

Comment: Whether your plugin is working with all the functionalities that you have created and your plugin is listed in the Menus listed in the Left Side of the WP Dashboard

Comment: Thank you Naresh with the help of User Role Editor Plugin and Adminimize i have fixed the problem .. it was actually user role issue :) Thank you  very much again!

Comment: You r Welcome @user3611783. Keep rocking with it.